# Forcing IE to render output in table

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

Can I make internet explorer render the page when in php i use

```
flush()
```

In a table, Internet explorer will wait for the rest of the < table> before it renders the information. Firefox renders it straight away.

Edit:
I'm using a table to display live information about servers and services.
For example:

1st column is the server name.

2nd column is servers status, I get this by pinging the machine.

Is there a better way to display this information?

Comment: `flush()` just sends whatever output you have in the buffer out to the client browser. If the client web browser doesn't render it, the only thing you can do is change what you output to something that the client browser does render.

Comment: +1 Although I just think that's how IE works. Hence (one of) the reasons we don't use table for layouting anymore. (<-- among many others)

Comment: So basically what @yes123 said. If IE will refuse to render a partially-coded table, change the format to something other than a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest moving on to using a list instead of a table. this way, it's faster. mark-up is somewhat similar so you can't go wrong.

```
<ul class="servers">
    <li>
        <span class="serverName">server1</span>
        <span class="serverStatus">OK</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="serverName">server2</span>
        <span class="serverStatus">NOT OK</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `table-layout: fixed` in your stylesheet will stop some browsers (probably including IE) waiting for the whole table before rendering it (of course it will also stop browsers re-rendering it based on content size).

Answer (score 2):

No, simply calling `flush()` causes PHP to push its buffer to the web server, nothing more.  Even if IE has the data for the table, it won't render it ahead of time.

The only thing you could do would be to create a table with JavaScript and add to it, piece by piece.  Of course, this is ridiculous though, and you should never do it.  It will be incredibly slow.

There is nothing you can do about this behavior (short of Quentin's suggestion, which changes your layout), and certainly not server-side.